# Use NSPredicate to filter object in core data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have three entities A, B, C.

The relationship between them is: A <-->>B, B<-->C.

A has a attribute called 'type'.

A and B relationship is a2b, B and C relationship is b2c. c_array is list of C object.

What I am trying to do is using NSPredicate to filter A by C and A's attribute 'type'.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"A" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSMutableArray *parr = [NSMutableArray array];

for (C *c in c_array) {
  [parr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY a2b.b2c = %@", c]];
}

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:parr], [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = %i", 0], nil]];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

But what I get is not I expected. So I tried other as well.

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type=%i AND (0!=SUBQUERY(a2b,$a2b,$a2b.b2c IN %@).@count)", 0, c_array];
```

Unexpected result happened again! Can somebody help me out? T T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do it the other way around. You already have the C's, and based on the relationships you've described, your C class would have a B property, and your B class would have an A property. So assuming you've used `c2b` and `b2a` something like this should work:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"c2b.b2a.type == %@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

NSArray *result = [c_array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Also I notice you're comparing the `type` attribute of `A` to an int in your predicate. Just looking for `type==%i` where i is 0 will return all objects that have no value in `type`. So either compare `type` to an `NSNumber` object or `type.intValue` to the int.

Comment: Thanks for your reply : ) I have solved this problem by checking line by line. I found I missed one relationship between C and B when I add B. Sorry about my stupid mistake. But you indicated NSNumber problem, that's helpful to me, Thanks.